# Remote Desktop connection IPv6

Tags: xrdp

I am working at Ubuntu 12.04 64bit. I have installed `gnome-desktop` and `xrdp`. Everything seems to be right but when Im trying to connect by Remote Desktop Connection in Windows 7 I can see this error picture:

[image]

I dont know why. I am connecting by IPv6 because in `vps.me` free users haven't no dedicated IPv4 only a shared but I can't connect anyway by shared I am totaly unskilled. Thats why I really need help tp set it up.

How to fix this ?

Comment: Still I have same problem. I found tutorial but I dont understand how to create "demo" file. [link](http://www.vps.me/forum/vps-hosting-tutorials/access-free-vps-me-ipv6-remote-desktop-vnc-from-ipv4-ipv6-to-ipv4-proxy) can anyone help me?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it can't be reproduced because its author has not signed in to Ask Ubuntu for 9 years.

Comment: @karel I respectfully disagree. The OP hasn't been on Ubuntu in years is not a (good) reason to close a question at all. Unless the comment was deleted, I don't see _any_ requests for additional (missing) information. Also, it isn't "not reproducible" because the OP hasn't signed in - it might be lacking information, but then it can be closed for that, but "OP is inactive" isn't a good reason to close a question.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error last night trying to get Windows RDP and XRDP to work together. On your windows machine, go to Control Panel > System then select Remote Settings on the left side menu. In the next window, click on the Remote Tab if it isn't open, then make sure Allow Remote Assistance at the top and Allow Connections from any version of remote desktop in the lower half are both selected, and click Apply to save. This got me past this particular error while still having IPv6 active.